# Redirect from second view

Tags: python, django, http, http-headers

Got a real problem here. I have got 2 views in backend and really need to redirect FROM second view

Views like this:

```
def first_function(request):
    """ Here is some stuff """
    second_function(request)
    return render(request, 'first.html', context)

def second_function(request)
    """ Check here something """
    if ok:
        return
    else: 
        return redirect('/') # this redirect does not work
```

Answer (score 1):

Your view `second_function` returns a response. As long as the view doesn't raise an exception, your `first_function` will continue, whatever the status code of that response.

If you want to return the redirect, then you'll have to assign the result to a status code, then you'll have to assign the result of `second_function` to a variable, then check the status code.

```
def first_function(request):
    """ Here is some stuff """
    response = second_function(request)
    if response.status_code == '302':
        return response
    return render(request, 'first.html', context)
```

This isn't a good way to structure your code, but I can't suggest an alternative because your code show what you're really trying to do.